# Download a file when an URL is given - iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4, download, nsurlconnection, nsurl

Is it possible to download a file from internet store it in document directory when an URL is given? I went through some documents in apple developer's site. It said that its possible using NSURLDownload, but it cannot be used in iOS. So, it should be done by using NSURLConnection only in case of iOS. So, someone help me download a file(even the HTML page) from the given URL. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of getting an image from a server and saving it to a file.

Create your instance variables

```
NSMutableData *activeDownload;
NSURLConnection *imageConnection;
```

Now create your connection

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"URL TO FILE"];
[request setURL:url];
[url release];
url = nil;

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Handle receiving data

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.activeDownload appendData:data];
}
```

Transfer finished, save the data

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *fileName = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.imageFileName];

[self.activeDownload writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];

self.activeDownload = nil;
self.imageConnection = nil;
}
```

There are other bits of the code I've not shown (properties, etc), but this should give you enough to help, I think.

Comment: I used this code and it works fine but I think there are a couple of things to be said, or people with less experience wont be able to make it work: 1) NSURLConnection *conn is better to make it as instance variable or Xcode will give an alert as the variable is not used... 2) When launching the download you'll also need to initialize the activeDownload variable (self.activeDownload = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];) or it wont save anithing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#downloading_the_response_to_a_file) library will help you :)

> **ASIWebPageRequest**
>
> The ASIWebPageRequest class included with ASIHTTPRequest lets you download complete webpages, including external resources like images and stylesheets.

Code Example from [allseeing-i.com](http://allseeing-i.com/)

```
- (IBAction)loadURL:(NSURL *)url
{
   // Assume request is a property of our controller
   // First, we'll cancel any in-progress page load
   [[self request] setDelegate:nil];
   [[self request] cancel];

   [self setRequest:[ASIWebPageRequest requestWithURL:url]];
   [[self request] setDelegate:self];
   [[self request] setDidFailSelector:@selector(webPageFetchFailed:)];
   [[self request] setDidFinishSelector:@selector(webPageFetchSucceeded:)];

   // Tell the request to embed external resources directly in the page
   [[self request] setUrlReplacementMode:ASIReplaceExternalResourcesWithData];

   // It is strongly recommended you use a download cache with ASIWebPageRequest
   // When using a cache, external resources are automatically stored in the cache
   // and can be pulled from the cache on subsequent page loads
   [[self request] setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];

   // Ask the download cache for a place to store the cached data
   // This is the most efficient way for an ASIWebPageRequest to store a web page
   [[self request] setDownloadDestinationPath:
      [[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] pathToStoreCachedResponseDataForRequest:[self request]]];

   [[self request] startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)webPageFetchFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest
{
   // Obviously you should handle the error properly...
   NSLog(@"%@",[theRequest error]);
}

- (void)webPageFetchSucceeded:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest
{
   NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:
      [theRequest downloadDestinationPath] encoding:[theRequest responseEncoding] error:nil];
   // Note we're setting the baseURL to the url of the page we downloaded. This is important!
   [webView loadHTMLString:response baseURL:[request url]];
}
```

Comment: This is for downloading entire webpages.  The original question was asking for downloading "a file".  Is it possible to download arbitrary files with this library?

Comment: Ok, I've misunderstood that, but the library can also download normal files of any size.

Comment: That's interesting to know that this library exists.  Might be useful in the future!  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do it with NSURLConnection. You need to make a request to URL. Something like this.

```
NSString *strDownloadURL = @"File URL";
NSMutableURLRequest *request  = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strDownloadURL]];

Connection *con = [[[Connection alloc] init];
con.delegate=self;
[[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:con] autorelease];
```

Now, in Connection Delegate Method didReceiveData Assign NSData to Global Variable.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {
  if (receivedData != nil) {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
  } else {
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
  }
}
```

Finally, In Connection delegate Method "connectionDidFinishLoading" You should have your file data in NSData Format. So store it in Document directory something like this.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
  [receivedData writeToFile:DocumentPathtoSaveFile atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I created that Connection Custom class for some my personal use. You can just replace"Connection *con = [[[Connection alloc] init]; con.delegate=self; [[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:con] autorelease];" to this  "NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];"